# After setting the Java1.8, `$ ./gradlew test` at compileJava of circleCI becomes Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, gradle, yaml

After setting the Java1.8, `$ ./gradlew test` at compileJava of circleCI becomes Build failed with an exception.

**environment**

- Java1.8
- gradle
- circleCI

**build.gradle**

I added a version of Java1.8 to build.gradle.
Omitted before and after.

```
def jdkVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceCompatibility = jdkVersion
targetCompatibility = jdkVersion

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = defaultEncoding
processResources.destinationDir = compileJava.destinationDir
```

**circle.yml**

```
machine:
  java:
    version:
      oraclejdk8
```

**$ ./gradlew test**

```
> Building 0% > :compileJava:compileJava 
> Building 0%FAILED
> Building 0%
> Building 0%14%
> Building 14%FAILURE: 
> Building 14%Build failed with an exception.
> Building 14%
> Building 14%
> Building 14%* What went wrong:
> Building 14%Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Building 14%> 
> Building 14%invalid source release: 1.8
> Building 14%
> Building 14%* Try:
> Building 14%Run with 
> Building 14%--stacktrace
> Building 14% option to get the stack trace. Run with 
> Building 14%--info
> Building 14% or 
> Building 14%--debug
> Building 14% option to get more log output.
> Building 14%
> Building 14%BUILD FAILED
> Building 14%
> Building 14%
> Building 14%Total time: 10.917 secs

> Building 14%./gradlew test returned exit code 1
```

Please someone help!!

Comment: What version of Java are you running Gradle with? If you do `gradle -version` what does it say?

Comment: `gradle -version`  Gradle 2.2.1,JVM:1.8.0_31 (Oracle Corporation 25.31-b07) is output.

Comment: @MikeKobit, have you tried running it with `-s` and `-d` as suggested?